# Problem getting custom validation firing in Angular templated form

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular-forms

I've created a Directive for custom validation of a UserName form field, but unable to get it to fire for the desired form element:

```
@Directive({  
  selector: '[appValidateName]',  
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ValidateNameDirective, multi: true }]  
})  
export class ValidateNameDirective implements Validator {      
  validate(control: FormControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {  
    return {"results": false};
  }  
}
```

and the form template:

```
<form class="sign-up-form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #accountForm="ngForm">
  <p>
    <mat-form-field class="sign-up-field" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput required [(ngModel)]="account.first_name" id="first_name" appValidateName name="first_name" class="form-control" #first_name="ngModel">
      <mat-error *ngIf="!first_name.valid">First Name is required</mat-error>{{first_name.valid}}
    </mat-form-field>
  </p>
</form>
```

...The `required` validator does work correctly, but I'm setting a breakpoint in my custom validator, and it's never being hit, even though the `appValidateName` attribute exists on this field.

Comment: does it hit your custom validator if you remove the required validator?

Comment: No, after I remove the required attribute, there is no validation at all

Comment: I don't write too many template driven forms, so I will let someone else answer. Another first question I would ask, do you need to/did you register the Directive in this or a shared module?

Comment: Yes, it is registered

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Maybe there are some problems with the `mat-form-field` usage.